Google OIDC Userinfo response includes "id" instead of "sub"
I'm testing OIDC authorization for a web application. For testing purposes I'm using my own google OIDC config.
When verifying the userinfo response I need to compare "sub" from the userinfo response with "sub" from the JWT token. However, instead of the "sub" claim I receive the "id" claim instead. The id claim has the same value as the sub claim in the token so I could in theory just compare those two,
however I'd like to understand why I'm getting "id" instead of "sub". It seems "sub" is a mandatory response field in the OIDC specification, so I'm not understanding why I'm getting "id" instead.
Userinfo response:
{
"id": "123456789",
"email": "notmyrealemail@gmail.com",
"verified_email": true,
"name": "Pol de krosmol",
"given_name": "Pol",
"family_name": "de Krosmol",
"picture": "",
"locale": "en"
}
scopes used: openid profile email
I tried to look in the OIDC config if I could somehow specify the "sub" claim to be returned by google with no success.
